# What is the anti-pattern for modules that group objects of the same type?

Tags: python, domain-driven-design, solid, anti-patterns

In MVC, I often seen all models in a `models.py` module, all views in a `views.py` module, and the controller - you guessed it - in a `controller.py` module. In other projects, I sometimes see all exception types grouped in an `errors.py` module. In a recent project, I saw all SQL query strings for all tables in a `queries.py` module. In other words, the motivation for grouping objects in modules seems to be that they share the same type.

I believe this is an anti-pattern because it violates at least a couple SOLID principles:

- Single-responsibility principle: there could be multiple reasons to modify any of the modules in my examples.
- Interface-segregation principle: anyone importing from `errors.py`, for example, is exposed to all errors.

I also believe this goes against domain-driven design because none of the examples speak about the business domain, e.g. listing the files from the MVC example - `models.py`, `views.py`, `controller.py` - doesn't give any clue what the application is about.

Is this really an anti-pattern? If so, is there a name for this anti-pattern?

Comment: Really? Are questions about names of anti-patterns off-topic here?

Answer (score 5):

The problem isn't grouping objects of the same type. It's choosing types to group that don't help. No one wants a car that keeps the tires and the steering wheel together in a compartment labeled "round things".

That sounds ridiculous because it is, but people will often grab onto a simple pattern like MVC and force everything to fit in it just so they don't have to think about high level design. For a while it works but then it doesn't and it's hard to see when that line is crossed. And now that we're here a lot of work has to be redone to get back to a design that works well.

But does this have a name? No, but there is an article that talks about this problem. I see you've already been exposed to many of Uncle Bob's ideas. I'll hit you with another one: [Screaming Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2011/09/30/Screaming-Architecture.html). Rather than being the name of an anti-pattern this is Bob's argument that your domain should be expressed at a high architectural level. The codebases domain shouldn't be something you would only discover after digging into the low level details of the code. If you blindly stick to grouping by types that don't express your domain that's exactly the trap you fall into.

That said, MVC is not an anti-pattern. It solves a recurring problem. But it can certainly be abused. Just because you use MVC doesn't mean you can only have 3 modules.

Comment: The "Model" part of MVC is where you put the additional architecture.